# copy output in front of specific characters (:*:) from each line in a list using Notepad ++ or in linux

Tags: linux, notepad++

I have a list where I would like to copy every word in from of :* on each line to create a new list.

for example
current list -

```
 - ftp1:*:1737:199:User &:/home/ftp1:/bin/clish  
 - juan:*:1738:199:User &:/home/juan:/bin/clish 
 -  kevin:*:1739:199:User &:/home/kevin:/bin/clish   
 -  mailer:*:1740:199:User &:/home/mailer:/bin/clish
```

new list or file -

```
 - ftp1  
 - juan  
 - kevin  
 - mailer
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^:]+).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^         : begining of line
  ([^:]+) : group 1, every thing that is not a colon
  .+      : 0 or more any character
$         : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1        : group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
ftp1
juan
kevin
mailer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat inputfile | sed 's/:.*//' > outputfile
```

I would just delete everything from the first colon onward. I recommend you look for sed examples. There are many.